# Mongoengine - TypeError: Instantiating a document with positional arguments is not supported

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have created Document Definition as -

```
class Post(Document):
    title = StringField(required=True, max_length=200)
    content = StringField(required=True)
    author = StringField(required=True, max_length=50)
    published = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

and I am inserting data from json file --

```
data_json = json.load(data_file)
post_1 = Post(data_file)
post_1.save()
```

I am getting error as -

> TypeError: Instantiating a document with positional arguments is not
>   supported. Please use field_name=value keyword arguments.

Is there no support to pass json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to unpack the dict--
 Post(**data)